# Rewrite Mailgun curl script for PHP

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

The mailgun API documentation suggest using the following script for adding users to a mailing list via curl:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/LIST@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/members \
-F subscribed=True \
-F address='bar@example.com' \
-F name='Bob Bar' \
-F description='Developer' \
-F vars='{"age": 26}'
```

I am trying to rewrite this so that it works with PHP:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
  "subscribed"  => "True",
  "address" => "bar@example.com",
  "name" => "Bob Bar"
));

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/LIST@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/members');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:{YOUR_API_KEY}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($result);
```

I am obviously replacing both `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/LIST@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/members` and `YOUR_API_KEY` with the appropriate strings, however it is failing.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the failure?  Does it return an error message?

Comment: It's not clear exactly how or where that's failing, but you might want to look into using their official PHP library to save doing all this yourself: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

Comment: @EatPeanutButter there is no error message returned.  It seems to fail silently and nothing is printed for result.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error somewhere causing the script to fail. Turn error reporting on diagnose the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved using the following code:

```
$data = array(
  "subscribed"  => "True",
  "address" => "bar@example.com",
  "name" => "Bob Bar"
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/LIST@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/members');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:YOUR_API_KEY");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($result);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: According to the docs [https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists] 'subscribed' must be 'yes'.

Comment: For whoever (like me) is scrolling up and down to compare the bad and good code: he removed the json_encode() call.